# Getting Unhandled exception with Segmentation error while running spring boot application in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot

I have written basic spring boot hello world application in eclipse. While trying to run an application, i am getting below error message. 
**Eclipse version- oxygen
JDK- 1.8
Spring boot- 2.2.5**

Error message

```
Unhandled exception
Type=Segmentation error vmState=0x00000000
Windows_ExceptionCode=c0000139 J9Generic_Signal=00000004 ExceptionAddress=00007FFCE167BF58 ContextFlags=0010000f
Handler1=00007FFC9526C210 Handler2=00007FFCB85FC830
RDI=000000000FC804E8 RSI=00007FFCE16984C0 RAX=0000000000360034 RBX=00000000C0000139
RCX=00007FFCE169D7B8 RDX=00007FFCE15D3570 R8=0000000000000000 R9=0000000000000000
R10=0000000000001112 R11=0000000000001000 R12=0000000000000003 R13=0000000000000003
R14=00007FFCC33DEF01 R15=0000000000000003
RIP=00007FFCE167BF58 RSP=0000000002EABFB0 RBP=0000000002EAC650 GS=002B
FS=0053 ES=002B DS=002B
XMM0 00007ffce169d588 (f: 3781809664.000000, d: 6.952694e-310)
XMM1 00007ffce169d550 (f: 3781809408.000000, d: 6.952694e-310)
XMM2 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM3 00000000001d0026 (f: 1900582.000000, d: 9.390123e-318)
XMM4 000000000fc81be0 (f: 264772576.000000, d: 1.308150e-315)
XMM5 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM6 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM7 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM8 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM9 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM10 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM11 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM12 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM13 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM14 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
XMM15 0000000000000000 (f: 0.000000, d: 0.000000e+000)
Module=C:\windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Module_base_address=00007FFCE1580000 Offset_in_DLL=00000000000fbf58
Target=2_90_20190205_265 (Windows 10 10.0 build 18362)
CPU=amd64 (4 logical CPUs) (0x1f93f0000 RAM)
----------- Stack Backtrace -----------
RtlRaiseStatus+0x18 (0x00007FFCE167BF58 [ntdll+0xfbf58])
RtlCharToInteger+0x35c (0x00007FFCE15EEEDC [ntdll+0x6eedc])
memset+0x9463 (0x00007FFCE162C3E3 [ntdll+0xac3e3])
LdrGetDllHandleByMapping+0x578 (0x00007FFCE15AE2B8 [ntdll+0x2e2b8])
LdrGetDllHandleByMapping+0xb8f (0x00007FFCE15AE8CF [ntdll+0x2e8cf])
RtlMultiByteToUnicodeSize+0x410 (0x00007FFCE15A24D0 [ntdll+0x224d0])
RtlMultiByteToUnicodeSize+0x178 (0x00007FFCE15A2238 [ntdll+0x22238])
LdrLoadDll+0xe4 (0x00007FFCE15A16F4 [ntdll+0x216f4])
LoadLibraryExW+0x170 (0x00007FFCDEA856D0 [KERNELBASE+0x256d0])
j9port_init_library+0x22c1f (0x00007FFCB86055EF [j9prt29+0x255ef])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0x26514 (0x00007FFC9529DB84 [j9vm29+0xadb84])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0x25c6b (0x00007FFC9529D2DB [j9vm29+0xad2db])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0x268ec (0x00007FFC9529DF5C [j9vm29+0xadf5c])
JVM_OnLoad+0x28f (0x00007FFC949965BF [jclse7b_29+0x365bf])
J9VMDllMain+0x134 (0x00007FFC94996E54 [jclse7b_29+0x36e54])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0x7c69 (0x00007FFC9527F2D9 [j9vm29+0x8f2d9])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0x90520 (0x00007FFC95307B90 [j9vm29+0x117b90])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0xd0c3 (0x00007FFC95284733 [j9vm29+0x94733])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0xea51 (0x00007FFC952860C1 [j9vm29+0x960c1])
j9port_init_library+0x1b25f (0x00007FFCB85FDC2F [j9prt29+0x1dc2f])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0xecd0 (0x00007FFC95286340 [j9vm29+0x96340])
J9_CreateJavaVM+0x89 (0x00007FFC952776F9 [j9vm29+0x876f9])
JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x786 (0x00007FFCAB7F1C56 [jvm+0x11c56])
JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x351 (0x00007FFCD13F8601 [jvm+0x8601])
(0x00007FF61E8A239A [javaw+0x239a])
(0x00007FF61E8ACF97 [javaw+0xcf97])
(0x00007FF61E8AD02B [javaw+0xd02b])
BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14 (0x00007FFCE13D7BD4 [KERNEL32+0x17bd4])
RtlUserThreadStart+0x21 (0x00007FFCE15ECE71 [ntdll+0x6ce71])
```

Can anyone tell me how i can resolve it?

Comment: This does not look like a Java issue at all … It looks to me that already the JVM start crashes. What JVM are you using? IBM's? Which Windows version? 64-bit for Windows *and* the JVM? What language settings has the system? Is it a RtL language like Hebrew or Arabic?

Comment: Eclipse OpenJ9 VM (build openj9-0.12.1, JRE 1.8.0 Windows 10 amd64-64-Bit Compressed References 20190205_265 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)